# JMeter: how can I achieve new Value from a csv, on each thread Iteration?

Tags: jmeter

Hello I do have a csv with the following format:

```
id,number,date
001,12345,2409
002,23456,2510
003,35432,2203
004,45432,2204
005,55432,2205
006,65432,2206
007,75432,2207
008,85432,2208
009,95432,2209
```

I want to have 3 Threads with 3 Iterations each and
each thread should peek an new random value on each iteration
How could I achieve this in Jmeter (version 5.4.3) with csv config elements?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

With JMeter's default [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) you can only have new **next** value on each iteration of each thread.

If you need next **random** value - take a look [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter), it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]